# Eclipse Logback Error on Launch

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed Eclipse Neon 4.6.2 and it launches with below error

```
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration:
The  org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration bundle was activated before the
state location was initialized. Will retry after the state location is initialized.
```

And the Eclipse screen disappears.

Comment: Hi - I believe you may be running into: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=489680

Comment: no I used to run neon 4.6.2 version on Ubuntu 16.04 to support java 8.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Later I found the root cause for it in my case.
If you have two java version running in your system (eg jre1.7 and jre1.8), and one of them gets updated (e.g jre 8) and overwrite the other one (which uses the jdk) then this issue might occur.

Better remove one of the java and try to open the eclipse, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted `.metadata` (folder) from my eclipse workspace then the problem got resolved.

Note that the `.metadata` folder will be hidden in workspace. So just go to your eclipse workspace and execute the command:

```
rm -rf .metadata
```

Also note you want to export your existing projects from the workspace once eclipse started

Comment: This worked for me, but you need to reimport all the project after that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was that Eclipse.exe was finding "the wrong" version of Java to use.

From the Readme supplied with Eclipse:

> **Specifying the Java virtual machine**

> Here is a typical Eclipse command line:

> `eclipse -vm c:\jdk11\bin\javaw`

> Tip: It's generally a good idea to explicitly specify which Java VM to use when running Eclipse. This is achieved with the " -vm " command line argument as illustrated above. If you don't use " -vm ", Eclipse will look on the OS path. When you install other Java-based products, they may change your path and could result in a different Java VM being used when you next launch Eclipse.

The solution for my situation was to specify the `-vm` parameter inside the shortcut that started Eclipse.  Rather than:

`C:\Users\Owner\eclipse\java-2023-12\eclipse\eclipse.exe`,

I changed it to:

`C:\Users\Owner\eclipse\java-2023-12\eclipse\eclipse.exe -vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\bin"`

and all was working again.